# How to make Typescript understand the type of custom v-model prop in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I'm using Vue 2 in a Nuxt app with `@nuxtjs/composition-api` and the following inside one of my components that has a custom `v-model`.

```
model: {
  prop: 'modelValue',
  event: 'change',
},
props: {
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  label: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  value: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  modelValue: {
    type: [Boolean, Array],
    default: false,
  },
},
```

**Template**

```
<UiCheckbox id="checkbox" v-model="checkboxValue" label="abc" />
```

**Script**

```
setup() {
  // Added any to silence the warning
  const checkboxValue = ref<any>(false);

  return { checkboxValue };
},
```

When I access to my component from outside, Typescript binds the value of a prop called `value` to `v-model` and not my custom prop `modelValue`. The inferred type is then wrong.

Is there a workaround for it Vue 2?

Comment: Could you add the lines of code where you actually bind the v-model inside the template?

Comment: I just added some context for clarity, you're right!

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like you didn't set this up correctly LMK if [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?redirect=true#model) will help you :)

Comment: I followed [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/08/creating-custom-inputs-vue-js/#supporting-v-model-on-custom-checkboxes), do you have any idea why it is not working in this example?

Comment: I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/theolavaux/53deebff47e3ab334c3553dd564cd923) with my full code (except styles), let me know if you can spot what's wrong

Comment: The types you gave to the boolean props (modelValue, trueValue, falseValue) are a bit off, at least in comparison with the guide in this article. You have them set to an array, while it's simply a string by the guide. And quite frankly, I find this guide confusing so following it line by line and double checking is the way to go IMHO. As soon as it works as expected, it's time to go nuts and start tinkering and tweaking it

Comment: This type property says that `modelValue` can be either a boolean or an array and that `falseValue` and `trueValue` can be either a boolean or a string, and that is correct right? It's not related to my original question though, `value` is/should be a string and I get an error on v-model because I'm passing a boolean and it's not referring the right prop (type inference should use `modelValue` instead)

Comment: Just for the sports, could you try changing ‘value’ from a string to a boolean? It might be happening because v-model automatically looks for ‘value’

Comment: Yes I know that it solves the problem! How to make Typescript understand that the prop associated with `v-model` is not called `value` but `modelValue` is the purpose of my question